# iphone upload image to facebook album with comment

Tags: ios, facebook, comments

I want to upload photo from iphone's Photos library to User;s photo album on Facebook along with a comment added from the User.All this should happen from within my iphone app.Is it possible using iOS facebook SDK with graph API ?
I would be so thankful to you guys for any related help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12486932/665823 it should give you an uploaded photo with caption message.

**------- Edit ------**

If your trying to publish on application album using SDK3.1 look at my post https://stackoverflow.com/a/13583440/665823 
.

**------- Edit ------**